# Django finding element by reverse relation vs filter function

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently working on django project, I am using reverse relationship for finding the element but at same time I can also use filter function.

for example models are:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    #some attributes

class Profile(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name = profile)
    #more attributes
```

if I have instance of Group (`group`) then I could use:

```
group.profile.all()
```

but also:

```
Profile.objects.filter(group=group)
```

What's the difference and which one is more efficient ??
I tried to find on google but unable to get a good solution.

What if I am using reverse relationship three to four times to find element?

Comment: These are exactly the same for the relationships you have posted; they are two different ways of saying the same thing. If you have a question about using a relationship "three or four times" you will need to post some example code.

Answer (score 1):

From DB point of view both queries are the same. You can use queryset's `query` attribute to check SQL query produced by ORM:

```
print(group.profile.all().query)
print(Profile.objects.filter(group=group))
```

result:

> SELECT "group"."id", ... FROM "group" WHERE "group"."user_id" = {user_id}
>   ORDER BY "group"."id" DESC

Answer (score 0):

all two syntax are same as database view.

but in some places first syntax usable and second is not.

for example when you render a template and in your template you have only group variable you can print all profile of that like this:

```
{% for profile in group.profile.all %}
    {# do anything with profile #}
{% endear %}
```

but in template you can not use first syntax

and in first syntax you can do more queries but not in first syntax. for example if you have two group to extract profiles first syntax is not worked.